# what is the best way to manage application user options in C# and sql?

Tags: c#, sql-server

My application has dozens of ComboBoxes filled with lists of values.

I wonder what is the best way to store these values in the DB since the user can add/remove :

1. Store in XML in Sql Server ?
2. Store in a text file on the server ?
3. any best practice ?

Thanks
John

Answer (score 2):

I would keep track of them in a table on SQL server.  If a user can define each field, then you simply need a table with a field name, value, and userid.  Then you can extrapolate all of it from there.

Of course, you would want to use a key of some kind linked to a table that defines each type of field possible, if needed.

One row per key/value (combobox) should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Another option to consider is to serialize your form in a json string that you'll store in a table in the SQL server DB. That way, you'll only have one entry per user to read. Then, you can deserialize the json string in an object that retains the properties of each control.

The big advantage of doing it this way is that if your form changes (and changes do happen!) you won't have to modify the data layer (ie. table definition + query).